# maven with eclipse error "Path must include project and resource name"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've recently started using maven with eclipse.

I've set up several projects and I've noticed that if I try and specify a build directory (to over-ride target) which is outside the project directory, I get an error when doing "update project":

'Updating Maven Project' has encountered a problem.

An internal error occurred during: "Updating MAven Project".
Path must include project and resource name: /[my project name]

I need to build outside the project.  How can I get around this?  Can I perhaps have maven automatically create a softlink?

Comment: `outside the project`? you can build only from the place the pom.xml exists that is the context root

Comment: build, copy to wherever you want using antrun plugin and delete the content from build folder

Comment: why can't I build somewhere like ../build ?  Is that a hard rule of maven?  Where is that written?

Comment: Because `Eclipse JDT` does not allow setting output dir outside of project. You can read it e.g. [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493229#c1). Maven itself supports such project layout.

Answer (score 6):

Although this is a fairly old thread, I recently encountered this problem and was able to solve it. The reason why maven threw this error is I had, somewhere in my `pom.xml` file, an absolute path that was not consistent with the directory from which the project was imported into eclipse. So I had two absolute paths (one incorrect, or points to a previous location) that point to resources, i.e. `project.build.outputDirectory`, in the `pom.xml` file.

The Solution: Locate the faulty absolute path, `/home/userA/ProjectB/bin`, and replace with a relative, `./bin`, path. Update the project in eclipse and you should be fine.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem, but it seems to me it's not the OP problem. He said *I need to build outside the project*.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit old thread, but since nobody gave a correct answer...

The following Eclipse error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name:
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:2069)
    at ...
```

can occur in many different scenarios - in the Eclipse Bugzilla you can find a lot of similar bug reports.

In situation you described, it is a **known limitation**. But it's not a `m2e` fault - simply `Eclipse JDT` does not allow setting output dir outside of the project.
IMHO it's a pity, because if maven supports a such layout, so I would expect that `m2e` should as well.

I've reported it as a [bug 493229](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493229). But it has been closed with status *WONTFIX*.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the last paragraph in your question, you can get around the problem with a softlink.  I did it a little differently than what you guessed at.  It's not Maven that creates the symlink because this is a problem with Eclipse JDT (as others have pointed out) which runs without invoking Maven at times (it seems).  Here's what I did, with all paths relative to my Maven project directory:

1) I wanted my actual build directory to be "../../local/java/scratch/target"

2) I created a softlink: `ln -s ../../local ./`

3) I added this entry to my "pom.xml":

```
<build>
  <directory>${project.basedir}/local/java/scratch/target</directory>
</build>
```

Now Eclipse JDT happily thinks it's building within the project directory but in reality the path "../../" takes it outside of the project directory.  My guess is that an absolute path would have worked too.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you'd like to have build contents in some folder outside workspace, you can have something like :

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <executions>
        <execution>

        <phase>move-build</phase>
        ////do your build
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>move-build</phase>
        // do your copying to external
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <executions>
            <execution>

        <phase>move-build</phase>
        // do your deletions from target
  </plugin>

</plugins>
</build>
```

then you can call `mvn move-build` to have your build, copy, delete done.

here is an example of [copy to external folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015434/maven-copy-file-from-workspace-to-folder-which-is-outside-of-target) and [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637626/remove-or-delete-resource-files-from-target-directory-using-pom-file), you can combine both into your move-build phase as described above

Answer (score 0):

`why can't I build somewhere like ../build`

Yes you can build in some folder called build provided it contains the `pom.xml`.

The `pom.xml` file is the core of a project's configuration in Maven. It is a single configuration file that contains the majority of information required to build a project.

In short the `pom.xml` will have all information to build your project.
`pom.xml` is a file which contains the project configuration details used by Maven. It provides all the configuration required for a project.

Answer (score 0):

I was convinced that this problem was caused by either Maven or Eclipse, perhaps because I found this and other references to that combination on Stackoverflow.

After considerable investigation, and going slightly mad, it turns out that Git was involved - though I don't know if it was the cause.

My Maven project consists of several "nested" POMs, and I don't open the parent POM in Eclipse, but only the children. I had a couple of files (batch scripts) at the top level which I hadn't committed to Git, but once I committed these the

```
Path must include project and resource name
```

problem disappeared completely.

> Eclipse version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)