# Error: Path must include project and resource name: / (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar:default-jar:package)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The titular error was prompted when I was trying to import a project created by Intellij to Eclipse, and after the importing whenever I tried to save an update to the files or update the project the same error was also prompted. I've searched tons of places and found the problem was actually pretty frequent on the Internet but there's not a single working solution as far as I could see. So I have to ask it myself just to get more attention to it--maybe from somebody who actually KNOWS the problem well and also has a solution to it. So here's some necessary information concerning my working environment: Eclipse Neon, Windows 7, and here's the full stacktrace:

```
Path must include project and resource name: / (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar:default-jar:package)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:2068)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.getFolder(Container.java:202)
at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.mavenProjectChanged(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:204)
at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator$1.build(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:144)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Here's the pom.xml that prompted the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent> <!-- This is where the IDE hints the error with a red squiggly underline -->
    <artifactId>communicate-api</artifactId>
    <groupId>cn.com.winsky.communicate.api</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>communicate-db-server</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>communicate-db-server</name>
<version>${project.parent.version}</version>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <!--<directory>E:\build\winsky_paltform</directory>-->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

The parent pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>cn.com.winsky.communicate.api</groupId>
<artifactId>communicate-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>communicateDbSever</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>develop</id>
        <properties>
            <communicate-db-url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.245:3306/communicate_api_db?characterEncoding=utf8</communicate-db-url>
            <db-username>testuser1</db-username>
            <db-password>test#2015TU</db-password>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cn.com.winsky</groupId>
        <artifactId>charging-db-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cn.com.winsky</groupId>
        <artifactId>fee-db-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.33.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>rabbitmq-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <directory>E:\build2</directory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>cn.com.winsky.api.platform.server.HttpApi</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-lib-src-webapps</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <copy todir="${basedir}/lib">
                                <fileset dir="target">
                                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                                </fileset>
                            </copy>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the absolute path in the parent pom.xml to a relative one. The reason why an absolute path is invalid is that Eclipse dose not allow setting output directory outside the project. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27562184/4357087

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different POM files. One for eclipse and other from command line. i.e.:

```
mvn -f pom-build-ext-dir.xml ...
```