# maven does not copy property file to specified destination in tomcat

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-resources-plugin

I am trying to copy property file in my project which is at the same level of pom.xml to a specific folder in tomcat. I am using the maven-resources-plugin. My maven version is **apache-maven-3.8.6**

**Following is the folder structure of where the duplicateReport.properties file is present**

[image]

**Here is the snippet in pom.xml**

```
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.4.2</version>
                 
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <overwrite>false</overwrite>
                                                    <outputDirectory>${env.CATALINA_HOME}/warfiles</outputDirectory>
                                                    <resources>
                                                            <resource>
                                                                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                                                     <includes>
                                                                            <include>**/duplicateReport.properties</include>
                                                                    </includes>
                                                            </resource>
                                                    </resources>
                                            </configuration>

                    </plugin>
```

In the environment variable (system variables) have set the CATALINA_HOME a below

```
CATALINA_HOME C:\Users\d_avi\eclipse-workspace\tomcat9
```

But when i try to access the variable in the output directory it is not able to resolve the catalina path, instead it creates the path in my project base directory

```
<outputDirectory>${env.CATALINA_HOME}/warfiles</outputDirectory>
```

This is how it creates

C:\codebase\combinedrepo${env.CATALINA_HOME}\warfiles
And in this location it places the duplicateReport.properties file.

**Following are the visual representation of the folder structure created.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Also when the absolute path is given in the output directory as below, it copies the file

```
<outputDirectory>C:\Users\d_avi\eclipse-workspace\tomcat9\warfiles</outputDirectory>
```

Also i have gone through this in stackoverflow
[Maven: copy file from workspace to folder which is outside of target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015434/maven-copy-file-from-workspace-to-folder-which-is-outside-of-target)

Also this [How to refer environment variable in POM.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463077/how-to-refer-environment-variable-in-pom-xml)

Any help or suggestions please, what is that i am missing here.

Comment: resources should be located in `src/main/resources` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise if the property file is not in src/main/resources, can it not be copied to the specified destination ?

Comment: What kind of specify location? resources are by default in `target/classes` ... or in case of a war packaging `WEB-INF/classes`... ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Specific location meaning, i am trying to put my properties file in Tomcat folder. The properties files is at the same location of pom.xml. If you can see the outputDirectory

Comment: First you should deploy a WAR file to tomcat and do not try to use Maven as a deployment tool there other tools for such job..furthermore you are using ancient old plugins ... please check https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ follow the conventions ...

Answer (score 0):

To have the include with specific folder name and also in the maven resources plugin, specify the destination folder, something like this:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-resource-one</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/destination-folder</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>source-files</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>foo.txt</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```